# using ruby on rails image_tag with angular.js expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to understand why if I use `image_tag` like this:

```
= image_tag "logos/logo1.jpg", alt: ""
```

it works just fine and I see the picture, but if I use it with angular.js expression, like this:

```
= image_tag "{{logo.imageUrl}}", alt: ""
```

i get error 404, in spite of the fact that `logo.imageUrl` is `"logos/logo1.jpg"`.

In the first case `img` tag looks like `<img alt="" src="/assets/logos/logo1-01ab28181850903257299595a6da4f477a3bbe814287214aa04844507a796502.jpg">` and in the second case it is `<img alt="" src="/images/logos/logo1.jpg">`.

Comment: Have you tried running `rake assets:precompile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because image_tag helper expecting first argument to be an already valid image path - url or file. If you want image path processed via angular you should use plain tags without helpers.

Source code: [image_tag](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/878e42916db8a18f61333f315907480d7c48c040/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb#L208) -> [image_path](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L310) -> [asset_path](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L130)